# Determine Class Associations using Reflection

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram, class-reference, class-relationship

I am working on a solution that extracts all the class associations between each other. If we click a class in the object browser we can see the option `Find All References`. I want something similar that finds the associations a class has to other classes. How can we find them using `Reflection`?

I am interested in Extracting

1. Composition Relationship:
2. Aggregation Relationship
3. Association Relationship
4. Inheritance

Comment: Reflection in .NET only inspects metadata, not IL. You would have to use something like Mono.Cecil to inspect a class and its members to see which types it is using.

Comment: IL means ? and have any idea ab http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17823/100-Reflective-Class-Diagram-Creation-Tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reflection` in order to list all properties, fields and methods (and more) of a class. You would have to inspect these and determine their types and parameter lists. Probably it would be a good idea to discard types from the `System` namespace.

```
Type t = typeof(MyClass);

// Determine from which type a class inherits
Type baseType = t.BaseType;

// Determine which interfaces a class implements
Type[] interfaces = t.GetInterfaces();

// Get fields, properties and methods
const BindingFlags bindingFlags =
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields(bindingFlags);
PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties(bindingFlags);
MethodInfo[] methods = t.GetMethods(bindingFlags);

foreach (var method in methods) {
    // Get method parameters
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();
}
```

Intellisense will tell you (almost) all the secrets of `FieldInfo`, `PropertyInfo`, `MethodInfo` and `ParameterInfo`. You might also consider examining the generic parameters of the class, events and more.

Comment: This would only retrieve types exposed publicly; you will be able to answer "what types are exposed by X", not "what types are used by X".

Comment: The `BindingFlags.NonPublic` will show you non-public members as well; however, local variables and types used locally in some way cannot be listed with reflection, but those won't be part of composition, aggregation, association and inheritance anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to parse the generated IL code, preferable with an understanding how they work. You can retrieve the IL code by calling [MethodBase.GetMethodBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx) followed by [MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.getilasbytearray.aspx).

You need to parse every byte according to the [OpCodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.aspx) enum. You'll also need to handle all opcode data, like offsets and tokens, since you shouldn't parse them as actual opcodes. Take the [OpCodes.Ldstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr.aspx) opcode for example; it consists of 0x72 followed by a token. This token is four bytes that should be parsed as an Int32, and can be resolved using 
[Module.ResolveString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.resolvestring.aspx) (since you know that ldstr has a string token). You can get a [Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.aspx) instance from [Assembly.AssemblyManifestModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.manifestmodule.aspx).